# Most efficient / quickest way to handle data storing for an animation tool

Tags: c#, animation, optimization, unity-game-engine, collections

If i had a bunch of values that were possibly non-linear but ordered: 1, 3, 8, 12 and i added a new one, say 5 whats the best collection type (speed over anything else) that would store it between 3 and 8 and gimme the index so i can check whats directly behind that value and in front. it's an animation system, i am storing keyframes and i need to know whats ahead and behind so i can properly interpolate the values

Currently i'm using a hashtable (dicitonary) thats key is the frame number the keyframe was stored at with the value being the position that i want.

So with this method, its very useful for updating a keyframe upon making changes, but upon animating, finding the 3 and 8 if I have placed soem data in 5 has me iterating through the entire list to figure out the index of the current entry and then store the previous and iterate to the next.. (not to mention that everytime i add something to the dictionary, it needs to be sorted by key for this to work).

Just looking for some suggestions to tackle this fairly open ended problem.

***To get some insight into my current structure for this animation tool:***

I have a component called a timeline, which is what KeyframeProperties record into. So in a keyframeproperty you would call record() and it'd ask the timeline it's connected to if it can record into the current slot, if it can, it'll return the index at which the keyframe was recorded, and then the keyframe property stores that index into a dictionary it currently has with the current data for the animator. When you choose the play the animation, you call the timeline.play() function and it'll handle iterating through all connected properties and calling keyframeproperty.advanceframe(int frame#). This is why i need the previous and next frame, cause without know this, when the frame# is passed in, theres no way to know where the next interpolated destination for an animation should be..

Example: Passed in a 4 and the closest two keyframes in the property are at 3 and 7, the animation should set the starting location to the 3rd frames data, then interpolate to the 7th by 0.25 (1/(7-3) = 0.25)

Comment: What about an array having one entry per frame. Array index == frame number. Any array position could be empty or contain a keyframe property.

Comment: Still has the problem of needing to be aware of the next closest frame within the keyframeproperty.  This would mean I'd be looping through all of the array in order to find the next and previous entry.

Gotta remember that when advancing a frame in the keyframe property, and you pass in a frame that doesnt exist, it needs to find the frames directly before and ahead in order to find out where in animation it should be

Comment: What sizes are you talking about? What's the mean and max distance between two allocated slots?

Comment: http://puu.sh/os7mF/e0d87fb291.png

The timeline will always have a mean of 0.  However keyframes for an object can be slotted anywhere within that timeline.
Using this image, if i wanted to animate starting at 3 to 13.  It would iterate through and animate from 3s position, to 4s, cause both of those are actual keyframes, whereas from 4 to 5 you would have to assume the position from the difference between frame 4 and 13s position and where on that frame 5 would lie

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is, how large are these numbers? If you have only 10 frames or 100 frames until the next frame, this should not be a problem. If you have 10,000 or 100,000 it might be a problem. Remember, today's CPU's are executing billions of operations per second.

Comment: Yeah i see what you're saying.  My numbers are fairly low (should only be about 30 keys per object max) but there may be a lot of objects and parameters that are executing simultaneously which could lead to hundreds of keyframes having these loops happening at the same time.  on top of this it's for mobile so i really gotta be careful for speed as well as resources

Comment: You need to click edit, delete ALL of your question, and just state in one sentence what you're looking for.

Comment: "Still has the problem of needing to be aware of the next closest frame within the keyframeproperty"  so just use an ordinary bidirectional list, what's the big deal?

Answer (score 3):

In terms of speed, there is no difference between an Array and a List or Dictionary unless you're dealing with a lot of data and executing methods on them intensively (say 100 times per frame). So, don't worry, just use whatever makes it easier for you, don't do [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any collection/container in .NET that returns you the index of the inserted item. At least the ordered ones don't provide that capability.

Your question is really more complicated than it seems on the surface. Because, as far as I can tell from the tags of your question, you are targeting Unity with your solution which uses a fairly old Mono implementation which targets .NET 3.5 profile. Moreover, since Unity has the capability to translate your C# code into C++ with IL2CPP (depending on the platform you are targeting) you might even need to think about how a C++ compiler will treat your code, whether it will vectorize your code or not. So, it's hard to give you a straight answer but I'll give it a shot...

If your data set is small (I would say less than a few thousand items, which is a relative number depending on your target platform) then you can use almost any collection/container of your choice and it won't make a big difference. And if that's the case then I would just go with [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.90).aspx) because it allows you to have a both the item you are looking for and its neighbors (the previous and the next items in the list) with one single search operation. In your case, if you have a reference to the LinkedListNode that contains the keyframe 5, you will be able to check where the previous and the next keyframes are by using the Previous and Next properties of the LinkedListNode object. It's just convenient...

If you have a large data set; first of all, what is more important to you, the insertion speed or the retrieval speed? Unfortunately, they go the opposite ways, so you will have to make a choice there. If the retrieval speed is what you favor, forget about the LinkedList Class, it's just too slow for iterating through large amounts of data. However, if you favor the insertion speed then LinkedList is a good alternative here as well because it won't have to sort all the data each time you add a value to the list. You can just insert an item at the location you want and all it will do is to change a few pointers here and there. The catch is that you will have to tell it where you want to add the item to. Meaning, you will still have to perform a search to find the location you want to insert the item to which will be costly but still not as bad as resorting tens of thousands of items.

If you are going to target IL2CPP then I would just forget about all of the above and use a simple array and implement all the search, insertion, sorting, array resizing operations myself. Because search operations on arrays are very likely to get vectorized by C++ compilers and that will give you a great speed bump for a large data set.

Comment: Hi Serkan.  I might say, you could just entirely delete your answer and type only: "try a LinkedList".  it's that simple.

Comment: Giving the fish vs. teaching how to fish Joe... You have got to explain the reasoning behind your answers if you want to do the latter. And no, the LinkedList is not the only thing I suggest in my answer if you read it fully.